# get closure's parameters class type in php

Tags: php, oop

lets consider this closure

```
$a = function (class_name $var){
  //
};
```

now I want to get get class_name before calling the function like `var_dump($a->parameter::class)` but its not working

so is there any way to access this class_name ?

edit:
this function can receive various type of classes so I want to know the class name and then include it.

Comment: What's kind of type-hint is `class_name`? What's that supposed to represent? It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @yivi , I edited the question , I think its clear now

Comment: But then, the type hint `class_name` does not really exist in your code, right? Please, if you are posting pseudo-code, say so in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use reflection, and especially [`ReflectionFunction`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) to access the parameter type:

```
class Foo {}
$a = function (Foo $var) {
  //
};

$function = new ReflectionFunction($a);
$parameter = $function->getParameters()[0];
$parameterType = $parameter->getType();

echo $parameterType->getName();  // Foo
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/E6lMM)**

Comment: thanks a lot. this works for me also I could solve the problem using abstract class.